# Implement a CRUD in Spring using an ArrayList of a Class

Tags: java, arrays, spring, arraylist, crud

I just started today to learn Spring (java framework) and I wanted to implement all CRUD methods by using an ArrayList of a class instead of using a database.

I managed easily to create the List and Add methods, but when the problem of the id arrive (for the remove / select / update methods), im really confused in my mind...

So here is my Pet Class :

```
public class Pet {

  int id;

  String name;

  int age;

  String owner;

  public Pet() {}

  public Pet(int id, String name, int age, String owner) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.owner = owner;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }

  public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
  }
}
```

Here is my arrayList and the CRUD methods:

```
private List<Pet> datas = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
private void initPetList() {
    datas.add(new Pet(1, "Medor", 12, "Peter"));
    datas.add(new Pet(2, "Mistigri", 5, "Jack"));
    datas.add(new Pet(3, "Pepette", 8, "Sarah"));
}

@Override
public List<Pet> getPets() {
    return datas;
}

@Override
public int addPet(Pet pet) throws PetAlreadyExistsException {
    for (Pet _pet : datas) {
        if (_pet.getId() == pet.getId()) {
            throw new PetAlreadyExistsException();
        }
    }
    datas.add(pet);
    return pet.getId();
}

@Override
public Pet getPet(int petId) {
    return datas.get(petId);
}

@Override
public Pet removePet(int petId) {
    return datas.remove(petId);
}

@Override
public int updatePet(int petId, Pet pet) {
    datas.set(petId, pet);
    return pet.getId();
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> listPets() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(petService.getPets(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet) throws PetAlreadyExistsException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(petService.addPet(pet), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Pet> findPetById(@PathVariable int petId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(petService.getPet(petId), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> updatePetById(@RequestBody Pet pet) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(petService.updatePet(pet.getId(), pet), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Pet> removePetById(@PathVariable int petId) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(petService.removePet(petId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So as you can see I try to create my remove method for example and catch the id of my class. But the problem is that my Id is a row in my ArrayList and when I create a new int called petId, this one will return the index of the array so if in my request I have : " http://localhost:8080/pets/1 " this will return array[1] which have for id "2" ! And I don't know how I can filter by Id and not by index !

What I need is like when I request id number 1, I want the array[0] with the value "1" for the Id.

If you have any advice for this. Thanks

Comment: Don't use a `List<Pet>`. Use a `Map<Integer, Pet>`, keyed by pet id. That way get-by-id and remove-by-id is fast. You can use Map's `values()` method to get list of pets.

Comment: One way is, you can iterate and remove the object if the given id matches the object's id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare provided `petid` with `id` of `Pet`. This allows to take correct PPet out of ArrayList. Change your crud methods:

```
    @Override
    public Pet getPet(int petId) {
    for (Pet _pet : datas) 
            if (_pet.getId() == petId) 
        return pet;
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pet removePet(int petId) {
    Pet pet =null;
    if((pet= getPet(petId))!=null){
        datas.remove(pet);
    return pet;
    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int updatePet(int petId, Pet pet) {
    if(petId<datas.size())
    datas.set(petid,pet);
return pet.getId();
    }
```